# Export to csv using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I am facing problem with  exporting `csv`.

Problems:

1) I have to export a html table to `csv` file . Can i change the delimiter of `csv` file to something else like semicolon. If I have values in the table under the same column separated by comma, in the `csv` sheet it is showing in a different column.

2) My code is not working for IE and it is only working for `mozilla`

3) Also I wanted the user to save the `csv` file. Now it is getting automatically saved.
Please find my code . Can any body help with any of the issue.

```
    function exportTableToCSV(filename) {

        var tab = $('#searchObjectTableTabs').tabs('getSelected');// selecting the table
        var tabIndex = $('#searchObjectTableTabs').tabs('getTabIndex', tab);
        var data;
        var rows;


        if (tabIndex == '0') // first index of the tab under which the table will be displayed
        {
            data = $('#dg');//Only one table
            rows = $('#dg').datagrid('getRows');


        } else if (tabIndex == '1') // second index
        {
            data = $('#doc').first(); //Only one table
            rows = $('#doc').datagrid('getRows');

        }


        var csvData = [];
        var tmpArr = [];
        var tmpStr = '';
        data.find("tr").each(function () 
        {
            if ($(this).find("th").length) {
                $(this).find("th").each(function () {
                    tmpStr = $(this).text().replace(/"/g, '""');
                    tmpArr.push('"' + tmpStr + '"');
                });                 


                csvData.push(tmpArr);
            }
            tmpArr = [];
            $.each(exportArray, function (index, value) 
            {

            csvData.push(exportArray[index].type + "," + exportArray[index].status + "," + exportArray[index].ID + "," + exportArray[index].itemrev + "," + exportArray[index].desc + "," + exportArray[index].owner + "," + exportArray[index].ogrp);
             });
            csvData.push(tmpArr.join('\n')); 
            // printObject(tmpArr);
        });
        alert('before this');
            var output = csvData.join('\n');
         csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(output);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
            'delimiter':';'
    });

    alert('done');
}


$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this,['export.csv']);
    });
```

Comment: Can you add the code and an example table to a jsfiddle so we can try and work out the problem?

Comment: Suppose in exportArray[index].type I have 3 values x,y,z.. They are coming in  a different column altogether since CSV is comma seperated. I want to get it under single column. So is there any way to change the delimiter in csv using the code??

Comment: Hi Andy .. Please find the below fiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/anbffh8p/4/